# Android: Cannot update my ADT version to 17+

Tags: android, sdk, installation, adt, android-virtual-device

I seem to have looked through many solution on here and the web and cannot find any relevant information towards the error I am receiving in Eclipse when I try to download the latest developer tools for android.

The SDK works fine, but the plugin for eclipse is giving me this error:

```
Your original request has been modified.
  "Android DDMS" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
  "Android Development Tools" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
  "Android Hierarchy Viewer" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Android DDMS 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.group 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762)
  Missing requirement: Android DDMS 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.group 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762) requires org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2' but it could not be found
```

When I target my SDK within Eclipse I aslo get the following message:

> This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 17.0.0 or
>   above.  Current version is 9.0.0.v201101191456-93220.  Please update
>   ADT to the latest version.

Can anyone give me any suggestions to solving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem:

I used this source: http://www.mobitechie.com/uncategorized/eclipse-android-development-tools-requires-org-eclips

This directed me to download eclipse classic found here: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Installing classic and checking for updates I gained access to download the sufficient ADT's to use the android SDK.

Thanks for commenting people!

Answer (score 2):

I too had the same problem. I resolved it by doing the following in Eclipse:

Go to Help -> Check for Updates -> Install all the Updates available.

This will install the android stuffs properly

Comment: I have done this, it did not work, giving me the first error message in the section above

Comment: Did you install all the Updates (especially the j2ee update)?

Answer (score -1):

Go to Help -> Check for Updates -> Install all the Updates available. only check on Android Development Tools then press next and accept install it